# Grep Multiple Things out of Order

Tags: linux, database, bash, grep, cat

I am currently working on creating a database in bash. I want to add an "and" function. This function will search for two things, and only return things that match both searches. How would I achieve that?

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

#return all
function all {
    cat people.dat
}
#return some
function search {
    grep -i "$SEARCH" people.dat || echo "search returned nothing"
}
#or search
function or {
    egrep -i "$search1|$search2" people.dat
}
#and search
function and {
    if [[ $(grep -i "$search1") = $(grep -i "$search2") ]]; then
        echo yes
        #that is temporary I want to see if it worked
    fi
}
#return null
function null {
    return
}

while [ true ]
do
    #get the search
    read SEARCH

    #search
    if [[ $SEARCH == *" OR "* ]]; then
        search1=${SEARCH%" OR "*}
        search2=${SEARCH##*" OR "}
        or
    elif [[ $SEARCH == *" AND "* ]]; then
        search1=${SEARCH%" AND "*}
        search2=${SEARCH##*" AND "}
        and
    elif [ "$SEARCH" = "all" }; then
        all
    elif [ "$SEARCH" = "exit" ]; then
        exit
    elif [ "$SEARCH" = "" ]; then
        null
    else
        search
    fi
done
```

Comment: Is this homework? I really hope you don't plan to implement a production database in Bash...

Comment: You can use sed like this: `sed -n "/$a/{/$b/p}"` for AND and `sed -n "/$a\|$b/p"` for OR

Comment: Can the search strings overlap? Example: `search1="a b"` `search2="b c"` string="a b c". Here `grep "${search1}.*${search2}" <<< "${string}"` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of first `grep` as input to second `grep`. Only lines with both `$search1` and `$search2` will be returned.

```
function and {
    if [[ $(grep -i "$search1" people.dat | grep -i "$search2") ]]; then
        echo yes
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

[@munircontractor is on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183652/96588). You can do it even simpler:

```
function and {
    if grep -i "$search1" people.dat | grep -qi "$search2"; then
        echo yes
    fi
}
```

The output of the first `grep` will be empty if nothing matches, the exit code will be ignored, and the output will be sent through the pipe. The second `grep` will stop searching as soon as it finds a match, will not print anything, and whether it finds something or not will determine the exit code of the whole pipeline.

Other tips:

- You can use simply `while true`
- You probably want to use `read -r` to avoid treating backslashes as escaping special characters